# Access a static variable by $var::$reference

Tags: php

I am trying to access a static *variable* within a class by using a variable class name.  I'm aware that in order to access a *function* within the class, you use `call_user_func()`:

```
class foo {
    function bar() { echo 'hi'; }
} 
$class = 'foo';
call_user_func(array($class, 'bar')); // prints hi
```

However, this does not work when trying to access a static *variable* within the class:

```
class foo {
    public static $bar = 'hi';
} 
$class = "foo";
call_user_func(array($class, 'bar')); // nothing
echo $foo::$bar; // invalid
```

How do I get at this variable? Is it even possible? I have a bad feeling this is only available in PHP 5.3 going forward and I'm running PHP 5.2.6.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection) to do this. Create a [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) object given the classname, and then use the getStaticPropertyValue method to get the static variable value.

```
class Demo
{
    public static $foo = 42;
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('Demo');
$value=$class->getStaticPropertyValue('foo');
var_dump($value);
```

Comment: I have noticed that getStaticPropertyValue($prop) does not appear to work if $prop is anything but "public static". It will bork if $prop is declared "private static" or "protected static" in the class. I'm not exactly sure why, though.

Comment: This makes sense, since it if it NOT public, you shouldn't have access to it from outside the class.

Answer (score 33):

I think there is much better (more elegant) way then creating ReflectionClass instance. I also edited this code (and my answer) after few comments. I added example for protected variables (you can't of course access them from outside the class, so I made static getter and call it using variable pattern as well). You can use it in few different ways:

```
class Demo
{
    public static $foo = 42;
    protected static $boo = 43;
    public static function getProtected($name) {
        return self::$$name;
    }
}

$var1 = 'foo';
$var2 = 'boo';
$class = 'Demo';
$func = 'getProtected';
var_dump(Demo::$$var1);
var_dump($class::$foo);
var_dump($class::$$var1);
//var_dump(Demo::$$var2); // Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Demo::$boo
var_dump(Demo::getProtected($var2));
var_dump($class::getProtected($var2));
var_dump($class::$func($var2));
```

Documentation is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I didn't think this would work if `Demo` was a variable...but it does.: `$class::$$field`

Comment: `$class::$$field` only works if you are using PHP 5.3 or greater, it seems.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to make this work for protected variables?  I'd rather not write a getter function if I can avoid it.

Comment: I think the question was about $class = 'Demo' not about $var = 'foo'. But yes it works in php >= 5.3

Comment: @Jonz - I think you're missing the point of protected variables. You can't access them from outside the class, and there's no way to change it - and I think you agree - it's good! But yes - you can access them from inside. I will edit my answer to show few other possibilities.

Comment: is there any way to make this work for special variables such as the class name under ::class ?

Comment: And what about from inside a namespace. Say you're in \Top\Middle and want to access ::class to get the full class name of something under \Top\Middle\Deep without having to build strings with tons of backslashes?

Comment: All you can do is very well explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Answer (score 21):

For calling static members you can use a code like this:

```
call_user_func("MyClass::my_static_method");
// or
call_user_func(array("MyClass", "my_static_method"));
```

Unfortunately the only way to get static members from an object seems to be [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-class-vars.php):

```
$vars = get_class_vars("MyClass");
$vars['my_static_attribute'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this?

```
class foo {
    static public $bar = "Hi";

    static public function bar() {
        echo "Hi";
    }
}

echo foo::$bar; // Output: Hi
foo::bar(); // Output: Hi

$class = "foo";
echo $class::$bar; // Output: Hi
$class::bar(); // Output: Hi
call_user_func($class, 'bar'); // Output: Hi
```

Comment: The question is 4 years old and explicitly refers to an old PHP version where `$class::$bar` was not possible yet.