# How can i access a variable that it is inside a static function from another file?

Tags: php, oop, psr-4

```
// * SELECTING ALL POSTS.
    public static function selectAllPosts() {

        $query = Database::Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
        $query->execute();
        $recipe = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        // THIS IS THE TARGET.
        $recipeImage = $recipe->recipe_image;

        return true;
    }

    // THIS IS ANOTHER PHP FILE.
    $recipe_image = Posts::selectAllPosts()->$recipeImage ?? "default-recipe- 
    picture.png";
```

i expect $recipeImage to be accessed from another file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a static variable by $var::$reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675676/access-a-static-variable-by-varreference)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access variables inside function.