# Why can't I use a placeholder to call a static property from a class?

Tags: php, class

Why can't I use a placeholder to call a static property from a class?

To illustrate:

```
class Foo {
   public $obj_property = 'works';    
   public static $static_property = 'does not work';
}

/**this works*/
$foo = new Foo();
$obj_prop = 'obj_property';
echo $foo->$obj_prop;

/**this fails*/
$static_prop = '$static_property';
echo Foo::$static_prop;
```

The error returned is `Access to undeclared static property: Foo::$static_prop`.
I understand that it is trying to look for `$static_prop` which doesn't exist. But why is it doing so?
Should it not be looking for `$static_property` - bc that is the value of `$static_prop`??

I'm sorry if this has been asked already - looked all over but couldn't find it.

(**Edit**: [Related question found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675676/access-a-static-variable-by-varreference) which asks how to access the vars. My question is more asking the why than the how. But the other question is definitely related and helpful.)

Comment: The `$` in `'$static_property'` is just a literal dollar sign. It doesn't have any special meaning from PHP standpoint.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `Foo::$static_prop` means "the static variable `static_prop` defined in the class `Foo`

This expression works :

```
$static_prop = 'static_property';
echo Foo::$$static_prop;
```

with the double dollar expression, first `$static_prop` is evaluated to `'static_property'`, then `Foo::$static_property` can be found.